# WSO2IS 5.10.0 - Issue to update configuration via deployment.toml file

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I deployed docker of WSO2IS 5.10.0 and mount the following volume:

```
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/backup:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/backup 
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/dbscripts:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/dbscripts
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/lib:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/lib 
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/solr:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/solr 
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/repository:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/repository
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/resources:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/resources
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/tmp:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/tmp 
    --volume /root/docker/wso2is/updates:/home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0/updates
```

my file deployment.toml:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 802 802   937  8 mars   2020 deployment.toml
```

```
[server]
hostname = "192.168.213.30"
node_ip = "192.168.213.30"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}:${carbon.management.port}"

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
type = "read_write_ldap_unique_id"
connection_url = "ldap://localhost:${Ports.EmbeddedLDAP.LDAPServerPort}"
connection_name = "uid=admin,ou=system"
connection_password = "admin"
base_dn = "dc=wso2,dc=org"      #refers the base dn on which the user and group search bases will be generated

[database.identity_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2IDENTITY_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[database.shared_db]
type = "h2"
url = "jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2SHARED_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000"
username = "wso2carbon"
password = "wso2carbon"

[keystore.primary]
file_name = "wso2carbon.jks"
password = "wso2carbon"
```

When I want to update my configuration via deployment.toml file I get the following error:

```
[2020-11-07 18:19:38,953]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Configurations Changed in :repository/conf/deployment.toml
[2020-11-07 18:19:38,957]  WARN {org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser} - Overriding files in configuration directory /home/wso2carbon/wso2is-5.10.0
[2020-11-07 18:19:38,961]  SEVERE {org.wso2.carbon.server.Main handleConfiguration} - Error while performing configuration changes
org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParserException: Error while deleting backup
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.util.FileUtils.deleteDirectory(FileUtils.java:118)
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.backupConfigurations(ConfigParser.java:167)
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.deployAndStoreMetadata(ConfigParser.java:178)
        at org.wso2.config.mapper.ConfigParser.parse(ConfigParser.java:127)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.handleConfiguration(Main.java:231)
        at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:103)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:70)
        at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:51)
```

Do you have an idea how I should proceed?

Thank you for your help.

Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the code related to the stack trace which you have provided.

https://github.com/wso2/config-mapper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/config/mapper/util/FileUtils.java#L118

Backup file was not deleted. hence the error was throwing.

Possible cause can be not having permissions for the user who is starting the wso2 server.

Comment: Thank you. I check permissions and they seem fine. drwxr-xr-x  2 802 802    6  8 nov.  00:13 backup

Comment: @PascalL the cause is that it tries to delete your mount and failing since it cannot delete the mounted directory.  ` https://github.com/wso2/config-mapper/blob/master/src/main/java/org/wso2/config/mapper/util/FileUtils.java#L108 ` please refer to the line of the code. the filename which comes to the line is "<IS-HOME>/backup". Actually, you do not have to mount the backup directory. it's created store the initial configurations at the server startup. since you are using docker and it's restoring everything at the server startup, you can simply ignore the mount and it will resolve your issue.

Comment: Thank you I just removed the mount to the backup directory and now it works just fine. You safe my time !

Answer (score 0):

Please check the permissions of **<wso2is-5.10.0-home>/backup** folder. It seems that folder doesn't have the required permissions to perform the backup deletion.
If backup folder permission is set as `drwxr-xr-x`, you will be able to do the config updates and start the server without this error.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Permissions are OK I checked twice. But I do not have any file in this directory. If I start the docker without any mount of volumes, I can see in the docker data in backup/repository/conf, but no any file if I mount the volumes to have persistent data. drwxr-xr-x  2 802 802    6  8 nov.  00:13 backup